# Angular, testing none-persistent data storage locally

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS, and I'm looking for some way (which might remind EMBER `FIXTURE`) to store 
none-persistent data only for testing purposes, before integration with server-side.

I try to store data in two ways one is regular copy and the the other is using `POST`.

[My Code - JSBin](http://jsbin.com/odiler/4/edit)

`Index.html`:

```
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
   <p>Phone List</p>
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
        {{phone.name}}
        <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
     </li>
   </ul>

   <p>Add New</p>
    <form>
       Name: <input type="text" ng-model="phone.name" /><br />
       Snippet:<input type="text" ng-model="phone.snippet" /><br />
       <button ng-click="add(phone)">SAVE regular</button> <br />
       <button ng-click="addRest(phone)">SAVE REST</button> <br />
     </form>
</body>
```

`JavaScript`:

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope,$http) {
   $scope.phones = [
                   {"name": "Nexus S",
                   "snippet": "Fast just got faster with Nexus S."},
                   {"name": "Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi",
                   "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."},
                   {"name": "MOTOROLA XOOM™",
                    "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."}
                   ];


   $scope.add = function(phone) {
          $scope.phones = angular.save(phone); 

   };

   $scope.addRest = function(phone){
           $http.post('phones/phones.json', phone, {});
   };
```

}

I use two functions invoked by two different buttons to store data.
I couldn't figure a way to put `phones/phones.json` in JSbin, but this is a `url` to a file which
contains a list of phones.

In Ember it was quite simple to define a model for test purposes but in Angular I cannot find the way
to test storing locally before integration with Server-Side.

It will be also very helpful to know why I see many people using `resource` to handle http methods
when I can simply use `$http.<METHOD>` in the controller for that.